# for looping in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've a table similar to this:
[image]

I want to use it for perfoming some operations in SQL server. How can I create a VBA code (for loops, to be more precise) to obtain one String similar to:

```
  sql = "select @Name = 'BookA', @price = col next to BookA where date in col D = cell("D1");
         select @Name = 'BookB', @price = col next to BookB where date in col F = cell("D1");..."
```

For instance suppose date in cell("D1") = '01.10.2015'

`sql` should equal to

```
"select @Name = 'BookA', @price = 101.651; select @Name = 'BookB', @price = 96.291; and so on"
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @ExcelHero, yeah, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this procedure in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub GenSQL()
    Dim i&, j&, sql$, v, k
    k = [d1].Value
    v = [d3].CurrentRegion
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2) Step 2
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            If v(i, j) = k Then
                sql = sql & " select @Name = '" & v(1, j) & "', @price = " & v(i, j + 1) & ";"
            End If
        Next
    Next
    sql = Mid$(sql, 2)
    MsgBox sql
End Sub
```